# How to flip x-y axis on click using d3

Tags: charts, d3.js, flip

I am using d3 chart to plot some charts.

I am looking for something by which I can flip my axis on a click of a button. Having said that I mean, I am looking for the functionality which seamlessly works for all type of charts like bar, line, stack etc.

Has anyone done some awesome work like this? Please help

```
Here is the sample
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adityasethi2601/ae5BP/

Comment: How to do this depends on the scale you're using. In principle, you need to reverse input or output domain.

Comment: I would be glad if you can give me an example. I basically wants x axis to become y and y becoming x. By doing that we will be able to see vertical bars instead of horizontal.

Comment: Oh that kind of flip. For this you have to redraw the entire chart -- first set up the scales with the new ranges, then draw the bars, lines and axes at the appropriate positions. I'm not aware of any examples.

Answer (score 3):

If you arrange your chart carefully, you should be able to achieve the flip with [SVG Transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) to rotate your image, translate it if necessary to new margins, and then reverse-rotate any text that you still want to be horizontal.

As a quick-and-dirty example, I've adapted your fiddle so that when the button is clicked, a class gets toggled on the SVG as a whole, which triggers a [CSS rotate transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) on the entire image.

Javascript:

```
    d3.select("div#chart > svg") ///select the svg
      .classed("rotate", function(){
        return !d3.select(this).classed("rotate");
          //check whether it is currently rotated
          //and set it to the opposite
      });
```

CSS:

```
svg.rotate{
    /* rotate the entire image */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ae5BP/6/

However, note that CSS transforms (which apply to html objects, such as the entire SVG when embedded in a webpage) are not directly equivalent to SVG transforms, so I wasn't able to get the "reverse-rotate" on text elements working.   To use SVG transforms, you'll need to wrap your entire chart in a `<g>` element to which you can apply the rotation.  You'll also need to figure out the appropriate "center of rotation" coordinate, otherwise things will be rotated around your (0,0) origin point.

But this should give you an idea of where to start.

*P.S.  I also adapted the fiddle to make proper use of JSFiddle formatting and the external resources option for loading D3 -- use this format in the future.*

Answer (score 0):

You could also draw two versions of your chart (vertical & horizontal bar versions), and achieve a similar affect by having the "Flip Axis" button toggle visibility between the two.

Comment: Would not be a bad idea? I was thinking to a create a function which could just flip the axis, having said that i mean to have a unique function which could do this for any chart be it bar or line or stack.